# How to get the raised error when using SqlCommand ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I catch a raised error in C#? (error level 16).
**The Following code does not catch the exception.**

```
 try
     {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
           conn.Open();
           string res = null;
           var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              if (res == null) res = ""; 
              res += (reader[0] as string);
           }
           return res;
        }
     }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    throw;
 }
```

I tried adding this code, but it did not help either.

```
    conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage);
    conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
```

Comment: Please clarify your question - your code already catches the exception? What more are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The Following code does not catch the exception.

Comment: How do you know there is an exception at all? Because your code looks like it should catch it. Of course, you are immediately re-throwing it...

Comment: I wrote something like that in the SQL script:
BEGIN TRY
EXEC('SELECT * FROM TTT');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 RAISERROR('XXX',16,1); 
 RETURN
END CATCH

Comment: Why would that raise an error? And why are you using `raiserror` rather than `throw`?

Comment: Why would that raise an error? Because in that DB there is no 'TTT' and when I run it directly in SQL it does raise an error.
Why are you using raiserror rather than throw? Good question, but - does it matter here?

Comment: The `SqlDataReader` returned by `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is `IDisposable` and should be handled correctly. Additionally all of its results need to be consumed before it can be guaranteed to throw exceptions. Callout to Dan Guzman's blog article, [The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions](http://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).

Comment: And `throw ex;` is just wrong, it will wipe the stack trace. Either just `throw;` or don't catch at all.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? What does the *actual* code contain? If you intend to throw in the SQL code why use `BEGIN CATCH`? Are you trying to use exceptions to return messages?

Comment: I use `BEGIN CATCH` because I have multiple actions in my Sql code, and if there is an error I want it should not proceed.
And in the C# I catch the error later and I Handle it.